# IntelliJ Gradle sync failure with libGdx project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm having trouble synchronize Gradle in my libGdx project with the Intellij IDE from Netbeans. On the terminal I get `Cause: invalid type code: CD` displayed.

When I synchronize it with eclipse it works.
It also works with the downgraded libGdx version 1.6.1 which uses `Gradle 2.4`.

Exception output:

> ```
>    org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Failed to notify build listener.
>    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify build listener.
>    Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
>    org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModuleIdentifier()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleIdentifier;
> ```

- `gradle-wrapper.properties`

  ```
    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1- 
    bin.zip
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
  ```
- `build.gradle`

  ```
    buildscript {


        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'


        }
    }

    allprojects {

        version = '1.0'
        ext {
            appName = "test"
            gdxVersion = '1.9.10'
            roboVMVersion = '2.3.7'

        }

        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
            google()
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        }
    }

    project(":desktop") {
        apply plugin: "java-library"


        dependencies {
            implementation project(":core")
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        }
    }

    project(":core") {
        apply plugin: "java-library"


        dependencies {
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"   
        }
    }

    project(":android") {
        apply plugin: "android"

        configurations { natives }

        dependencies {
            implementation project(":core")
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64" 
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: What IDE version is used? Please try to disable "Experimental | Only sync the active variant" option as suggested here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002683740-Gradle-failure-Java-11-with-Gradle-5-and-Cause-invalid-type-code-CD

Comment: I use the 2019.2.1 vesion. I just reinstalled Intellij and now I can compile my projects but i still get the sync error.

Comment: Have you tried to disable option mentioned above?

Comment: I have the same problem i actualy also posted this on stackoverflow.Its a bug needs fix